# Dynamically generate Powerbi Access Token (AAD Token)

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded

i'm using powerbi rest APIs in my react app.

for authentication I'm using copying static Azure Ad token (not an embed token) from their developers playground.

The token is only valid for an hour.

is there any way to dynamically generate it?

Comment: The easiest way is to use Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) to acquire tokens (e.g. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript2)). ADAL also supports refreshing the tokens, to support longer than 1 hour communications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

Based on your requirement you can add the API permissions:

[image]

I created an **Azure AD Application and added API permission** like below:

[image]

**`Offline_access`** API permission is required to generate the refresh token.

I generated the **access token** using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:*****
scope:RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

To refresh the access token, I used below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:refreshtoken
client_secret:*****
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Create a React single-page app that uses auth code flow - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react)

Comment: thankyou so much for being so helpful. however I want to achieve the same by using ROPC flow. in case you have any resources please share.

Comment: For ROPC flow, refer [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/ZSVwHhm.png) and refresh the token as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: i want scope for powerbi permissions. would it be graph.microsoft.com/.default ? i think it will only generate a token for graph API permissions?

Comment: Please use the scope as RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory

Comment: i tried. such error being thrown- AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '36506c86-7c6b-435c-ade9-539e2f859e92' named 'surfside dashboard'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

ALSO I'M NOT THE ADMIN OF MY TENANT, BUT THE AZURE APP IS CREATED BY ME.

Comment: Did you Grant Admin consent to the API permissions?

Comment: Not yet. because all the permission my app needs don't need admin content. pl see https://www.sochokuchnaya.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/scshot-768x400.png

Comment: Yeah but grant admin consent to the permissions and it will work

Comment: but if i set scope to 'user.read' then it generates a token https://www.sochokuchnaya.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/scshot2-768x350.png. however I need a token that has the scopes of dataset.readwrite.all in powerbi API permissions. 

also in azure ad inside 'expose an api' section, i have also added the same scope permission for my app manually. i don't know where am i going wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251746/discussion-between-rukmini-and-navinrangar).